# View Pager with scroll view inside a TabLayout

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-tablayout

I have an issue (not a big one i hope)

I change my layout in my app for adding the TabLayout in the design developper Librairy.

The issue is :

On one of my fragment (tab) i have a scrollview, but i can see the end of the scroll (missing some textview, and other UI element)

**Here my xml where there is my viewPager**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
           />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            android:gravity="bottom"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Here my xml view with the ScrollView**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                style="@style/bold_text"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

          <!--** A lot of thing inside not very important for the problem I think**-->
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**Edit**

Before trying to use TabLayout i have a custom Methode for SlidingTab :

**Here see the previous XML**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_class"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundapplication"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <theappbeginner.fr.dofuStuff.utils.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:elevation="2dp"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here previous code**

```
public class SlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView
{
    private static final int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;
    private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;
    private int mTitleOffset;

    private int mTabViewLayoutId;
    private int mTabViewTextViewId;
    private boolean mDistributeEvenly;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private SparseArray<String> mContentDescriptions = new SparseArray<String>();
    private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context)
    {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        // Disable the Scroll Bar
        setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        // Make sure that the Tab Strips fills this View
        setFillViewport(true);

        mTitleOffset = (int) (TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

        mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
        addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    /**
     * Set the custom {@link TabColorizer} to be used.
     * <p>
     * If you only require simple custmisation then you can use
     * {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)} to achieve
     * similar effects.
     */
    public void setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer tabColorizer)
    {
        mTabStrip.setCustomTabColorizer(tabColorizer);
    }

    public void setDistributeEvenly(boolean distributeEvenly)
    {
        mDistributeEvenly = distributeEvenly;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the colors to be used for indicating the selected tab. These colors are treated as a
     * circular array. Providing one color will mean that all tabs are indicated with the same color.
     */
    public void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors)
    {
        mTabStrip.setSelectedIndicatorColors(colors);
    }

    /**
     * Set the {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener}. When using {@link SlidingTabLayout} you are
     * required to set any {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener} through this method. This is so
     * that the layout can update it's scroll position correctly.
     *
     * @see ViewPager#setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)
     */
    public void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener)
    {
        mViewPagerPageChangeListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Set the custom layout to be inflated for the tab views.
     *
     * @param layoutResId Layout id to be inflated
     * @param textViewId  id of the {@link TextView} in the inflated view
     */
    public void setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId)
    {
        mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
        mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the associated view pager. Note that the assumption here is that the pager content
     * (number of tabs and tab titles) does not change after this call has been made.
     */
    public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager)
    {
        mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

        mViewPager = viewPager;
        if (viewPager != null)
        {
            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new InternalViewPagerListener());
            populateTabStrip();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a default view to be used for tabs. This is called if a custom tab view is not set via
     * {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)}.
     */
    protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context)
    {
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
                outValue, true);
        textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
        textView.setAllCaps(true);

        int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

        return textView;
    }

    private void populateTabStrip()
    {
        final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
        final View.OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++)
        {
            View tabView = null;
            TextView tabTitleView = null;

            if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0)
            {
                // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
                tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                        false);
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
            }

            if (tabView == null)
            {
                tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
            }

            if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView))
            {
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
            }

            if (mDistributeEvenly)
            {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tabView.getLayoutParams();
                lp.width = 0;
                lp.weight = 1;
            }

            tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
            tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);
            String desc = mContentDescriptions.get(i, null);
            if (desc != null)
            {
                tabView.setContentDescription(desc);
            }

            mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
            if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem())
            {
                tabView.setSelected(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setContentDescription(int i, String desc)
    {
        mContentDescriptions.put(i, desc);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow()
    {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        if (mViewPager != null)
        {
            scrollToTab(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
        }
    }

    private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset)
    {
        final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
        if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount)
        {
            return;
        }

        View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
        if (selectedChild != null)
        {
            int targetScrollX = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;

            if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0)
            {
                // If we're not at the first child and are mid-scroll, make sure we obey the offset
                targetScrollX -= mTitleOffset;
            }

            scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Allows complete control over the colors drawn in the tab layout. Set with
     * {@link #setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer)}.
     */
    public interface TabColorizer
    {

        /**
         * @return return the color of the indicator used when {@code position} is selected.
         */
        int getIndicatorColor(int position);

    }

    private class InternalViewPagerListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener
    {
        private int mScrollState;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
        {
            int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
            if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0) || (position >= tabStripChildCount))
            {
                return;
            }

            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);

            View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
            int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null)
                    ? (int) (positionOffset * selectedTitle.getWidth())
                    : 0;
            scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null)
            {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset,
                        positionOffsetPixels);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
        {
            mScrollState = state;

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null)
            {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position)
        {
            if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
            {
                mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
                scrollToTab(position, 0);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++)
            {
                mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).setSelected(position == i);
            }
            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null)
            {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
            }
        }

    }

    private class TabClickListener implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++)
            {
                if (v == mTabStrip.getChildAt(i))
                {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**And the other class**

```
public class SlidingTabStrip extends LinearLayout
{

    private static final int DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS = 0;
    private static final byte DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA = 0x26;
    private static final int SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS = 3;
    private static final int DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR = 0xFF33B5E5;

    private final int mBottomBorderThickness;
    private final Paint mBottomBorderPaint;

    private final int mSelectedIndicatorThickness;
    private final Paint mSelectedIndicatorPaint;

    private final SimpleTabColorizer mDefaultTabColorizer;
    private int mSelectedPosition;
    private float mSelectionOffset;
    private SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer mCustomTabColorizer;

    SlidingTabStrip(Context context)
    {
        this(context, null);
    }

    SlidingTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {

        super(context, attrs);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        final int mDefaultBottomBorderColor;
        final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorForeground, outValue, true);
        final int themeForegroundColor = outValue.data;

        mDefaultBottomBorderColor = setColorAlpha(themeForegroundColor,
                DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA);

        mDefaultTabColorizer = new SimpleTabColorizer();
        mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR);

        mBottomBorderThickness = (int) (DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
        mBottomBorderPaint = new Paint();
        mBottomBorderPaint.setColor(mDefaultBottomBorderColor);

        mSelectedIndicatorThickness = (int) (SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
        mSelectedIndicatorPaint = new Paint();
    }

    /**
     * Set the alpha value of the {@code color} to be the given {@code alpha} value.
     */
    private static int setColorAlpha(int color, byte alpha)
    {
        return Color.argb(alpha, Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color));
    }

    /**
     * Blend {@code color1} and {@code color2} using the given ratio.
     *
     * @param ratio of which to blend. 1.0 will return {@code color1}, 0.5 will give an even blend,
     *              0.0 will return {@code color2}.
     */
    private static int blendColors(int color1, int color2, float ratio)
    {
        final float inverseRation = 1f - ratio;
        float r = (Color.red(color1) * ratio) + (Color.red(color2) * inverseRation);
        float g = (Color.green(color1) * ratio) + (Color.green(color2) * inverseRation);
        float b = (Color.blue(color1) * ratio) + (Color.blue(color2) * inverseRation);
        return Color.rgb((int) r, (int) g, (int) b);
    }

    void setCustomTabColorizer(SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer customTabColorizer)
    {
        mCustomTabColorizer = customTabColorizer;
        invalidate();
    }

    void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors)
    {
        // Make sure that the custom colorizer is removed
        mCustomTabColorizer = null;
        mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(colors);
        invalidate();
    }

    void onViewPagerPageChanged(int position, float positionOffset)
    {
        mSelectedPosition = position;
        mSelectionOffset = positionOffset;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        final int height = getHeight();
        final int childCount = getChildCount();
        final SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer tabColorizer = mCustomTabColorizer != null
                ? mCustomTabColorizer
                : mDefaultTabColorizer;

        // Thick colored underline below the current selection
        if (childCount > 0)
        {
            View selectedTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition);
            int left = selectedTitle.getLeft();
            int right = selectedTitle.getRight();
            int color = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition);

            if (mSelectionOffset > 0f && mSelectedPosition < (getChildCount() - 1))
            {
                int nextColor = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition + 1);
                if (color != nextColor)
                {
                    color = blendColors(nextColor, color, mSelectionOffset);
                }

                // Draw the selection partway between the tabs
                View nextTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition + 1);
                left = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getLeft() +
                        (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * left);
                right = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getRight() +
                        (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * right);
            }

            mSelectedIndicatorPaint.setColor(color);

            canvas.drawRect(left, height - mSelectedIndicatorThickness, right,
                    height, mSelectedIndicatorPaint);
        }

        // Thin underline along the entire bottom edge
        canvas.drawRect(0, height - mBottomBorderThickness, getWidth(), height, mBottomBorderPaint);
    }

    private static class SimpleTabColorizer implements SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer
    {
        private int[] mIndicatorColors;

        @Override
        public final int getIndicatorColor(int position)
        {
            return mIndicatorColors[position % mIndicatorColors.length];
        }

        void setIndicatorColors(int... colors)
        {
            mIndicatorColors = colors;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding android:fillViewport="true" to your ScrollView?

Comment: which ui elements are missing and also post the related java code

Comment: @Orkun Koçyiğit nothing change with this property. UI elements which are missing are only textview.